# Programmatically create shape view and use on collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, cashapelayer

I create a custom view programmatically with swift. I created triangle view with CAShapeLayer, I use added on view controller. It's working fine.

But I use triangle custom view in collection view cell, it's not working.
Here is my custom view. How can I use it in collection view cell.

```
final class CardView: UIView {

    lazy var countLB: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 120)
        label.textColor = UIColor.red
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "500"
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    lazy var topTriangleView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        return view
    }()

    lazy var trianglePath: UIBezierPath = {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: frame.size.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width, y: 0))
        path.close()
        path.fill()
        return path
    }()

    lazy var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.path = trianglePath.cgPath
        shape.fillColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        return shape
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        addSubview(topTriangleView)
        countLB.layer.zPosition = 1
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        assertionFailure()
    }

    private func setupView() {
        addSubview(countLB)
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()
        countLB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        countLB.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What means "it is not working"?

You could check these:

You should add your CardView instance to the contentView inside the UICollectionViewCell, not to the view itself.

Maybe the updateConstraints isn't called, you could add a print statement to check if that's the problem.

Comment: "it is not working" means is triangle layer not showing. But other view showing normal. (like label). And I added in cell's content view.